# Entity Framework many to many to single object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to map a property on a user that that has a many to many relationship in the database but there is only ever one per user. But I am unable to figure out the required map in entityframework. I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //Need to map this property
    public virtual SecurityRole SecurityRole { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

An the following tables:

```
User:
    Id
    FirstName
    LastName
SecurityRole:
    Id
    Name
UserSecurityRole:
    UserId
    SecurityRoleId
```

If anyone has any idea or could point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: so a user can only have one securityrole? Why not remove this many to many table and just add the security role as a property of the user?

Comment: I would love to do that but I cannot change the DB structure as it is quite old and alot of dependent legacy sql scripts

Comment: Time for a new database?

Comment: Quite possibly but alot of work

Comment: You have to model the database structure, not the actual data in a particular instance. The fact thay in practice you will only have one SecurityRole per user, does not change the fact that you could have many, otherwise you have a model that breaks if the wrong data is in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is only one record in the database, if you have a many to many relationship between `User` and `SecurityRole` it should work like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<SecurityRole> SecurityRoles { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would much rather that user would only have one SecurityRole as there should only be one, but i cannot change the DB structure